# writing a game in c# winForm and program skips task before completing current one

Tags: c#, winforms

writing a windows Form program that takes user input, and changes the color of the label accordingly.
and when the program reaches 2 words it repeats itself. it works fine until it reaches the second
word, where there I added a method to restart from the beginning after "validating and changing color", I can see the program validated the word, but when it comes to change the color, it just skips that part and starts from the beginning.

```
public partial class Form1: Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

       string[] listOfWords = { "bike", "car" };
        Label[] labelsToDisplay = new Label[2];
        string currentWord = "";
        string userInput = "";
        int increment = 0;

      

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            labelsToDisplay[0] = this.label1;
            labelsToDisplay[1] = this.label2;

            for (int i = 0; i < labelsToDisplay.Length; i++)
            {
                labelsToDisplay[i].Text = listOfWords[i];
            }

            increment = 0;
            currentWord = listOfWords[0];
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyChar == ' ')
            {
                userInput = textBox1.Text;
                if (userInput.Trim() == currentWord)
                {
                    labelsToDisplay[increment].ForeColor = Color.Green;
                }
                else if (userInput.Trim() != currentWord)
                {
                    labelsToDisplay[increment].ForeColor = Color.Red;
                }

                     increment++;

                if (increment < labelsToDisplay.Length)
                {
                    currentWord = listOfWords[increment];
                }
                else if (increment >= labelsToDisplay.Length)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < labelsToDisplay.Length; i++)
                    {
                        labelsToDisplay[i].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                    Form1_Load(sender, e);

                }

                textBox1.Text = "";
                userInput = "";
               
            }
        }
    }
```

I initialize an array of words and labels.
load Event connects the labels of the designer to the label array.
then make equal the labels to the listOfWords array.
and I initialize currnetWord.

now the user enters data into `textBox1`.
once the user hits the "space" an event is triggered, that checks if the text the user entered is equal to currentWord. if it is that label turns green. and red if not equal.

I put an "increment" int that adds 1 every time user presses space to know where I'm up to

now once the "increment" is larger than the length of the label array it triggers the load event that starts the process again.

but the issue is that the program is supposed to start the process again only after changing the color of the label but instead it just restarts without changing color.
but when I put a `MessageBox` before running the `LoadEvent` or if I remove the load event the label does turn green.
(i tried `Thread.Sleep` but that just pauses everything)

Comment: Looks like you are resetting the colors when the increment >= labels length.  Unless I am misunderstanding and they are not being set back to black?

Comment: i am resetting the labels to black. but after the user input has been validated. and colors are "supposed" to be changed accordingly as well. but instead it jumps right to the next task.

Comment: I think the color does change, its just that they change to black directly after.  Are you looking for a delay between resetting the labels so that you can see it turned green before resetting the label to black?

Comment: Yes that be extremely helpful

Comment: You create the LabelsToDisplay, but you never make them visible?

Comment: i do just i didnt post the designer code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be a delay between setting the color to green/red and resetting all label colors to black.  Here is a way to do it, however it may not be the best way.  I first create a background worker and hook into the DoWork and RunWorkerCompleted events.  Inside DoWork we create the delay using the Thread Sleep.  Inside of RunWorkerCompleted we reset the label colors and call form load.

```
private BackgroundWorker bgWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    bgWorker.DoWork += BgWorker_DoWork;
    bgWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += BgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted;
}

private void BgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
private void BgWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    Reset();
}

private void Reset()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < labelsToDisplay.Length; i++)
    {
        labelsToDisplay[i].ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }

    Form1_Load(null, null);
}
```

and inside of your existing code i changed where the increment exceeds the array bounds

```
else if (increment >= labelsToDisplay.Length)
{
    bgWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

This will allow you to see the color before resetting the colors to black.

One thing to note is that the user will still be able to interact with the textbox and fire the KeyPress event.  You could add a boolean to track whether the event should fire or not, something like..

```
private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (isResetting)
    {
        return;
    }
    .....
}
```

Just make sure to set that bool to true when starting the background worker, and false once the worker has completed.